# Ruby Regular expression to find the binary gap

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to find the binary gap using Ruby regex
Say 1000001001010011100000000000, From left I want to use regex to match

A. 1000001 should return 00000

B. 1001 should return 00

C. 101 should return 0

D 1001 should return 00

My first attempt look like this but its missing the B and D

[image]

Update

A binary gap within a positive integer N is any maximal sequence of consecutive zeros that is surrounded by ones at both ends in the binary representation of N.

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it understandable.

Comment: What is a "binary gap? and how do you define it? Examples B and D are contradictory. Would `split('1').compact` do the job?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
/1(0+)(?=1)/
```

The problem with your pattern is that you consume the "closing 1". Consequence, the next research starts after this "closing 1". 
But if you use a lookahead (that is a zero width assertion that doesn't consume characters and only tests what happens after), the "closing 1" isn't consumed and you get the desired result, because the next research starts after the last zero.

Note that if you don't need the zeros to be enclosed between ones, you can also simply use: `/0+/`

Other way: if you are sure that the string only contains 1s and 0s, you can also use the (non-)word-boundary assertion `\B` with this pattern: `1\K0++\B`

Comment: I was about to answer that he might be referring to the need for non-capturing groups.

Comment: @Pyrce: be careful, non-capturing groups don't prevent to consume characters. See also, Cary Swoveland way that doesn't consume characters at all, since all is enclosed in a lookahead. Using this way, you can get all overlapping substrings you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
R = /
    (?=     # start a positive lookahead
      1     # match a one
      (0+)  # match one or more zeros in capture group 1
      1     # match a one
    )       # end positive lookahead
    /x      # free-spacting regex definition mode

str = "1000001001010011100000000000"

arr = []
str.scan(R) { |m| arr << [m.first, Regexp.last_match.begin(0)+1] }
arr
  #=> [["00000", 1], ["00", 7], ["0", 10], ["00", 12]]
```

The elements of `arr` correspond to all all substrings of one or more `"0"`'s of `str` that are preceded and followed by `1`. The first element of each pair is the substring, the second is the offset into `str` where the substring begins.

Here's a second example.

```
str = "10011001010101001110001000100101"

arr = []
str.scan(R) { |m| arr << [m.first, Regexp.last_match.begin(0)+1] }
arr
  #=> [["00", 1], ["00", 5], ["0", 8], ["0", 10], ["0", 12], ["00", 14],
  #    ["000", 19], ["000", 23], ["00", 27], ["0", 30]]
```

Note that one must use a positive lookahead, rather than a positive lookbehind, as (in Ruby) the latter does not permit variable-length strings (i.e., `0+`).

@Stefan, in a comment, suggested an improvement:

```
R = /
    (?<=1) # match a one in a positive lookbehind
    0+     # match one or more zeros
    (?=1)  # match a one in a positive lookahead
    /x      # free-spacting regex definition mode

str = "1000001001010011100000000000"

arr = []
str.scan(R) { |m| arr << [m, Regexp.last_match.begin(0)] }
arr
  #=> [["00000", 1], ["00", 7], ["0", 10], ["00", 12]]
```

This is similar to what @Casimir suggests (`/1(0+)(?=1)/`), except that by putting the first `1` in a positive lookbehind there's no need for the capture group.

Here is another way that does not use a regex.

```
str = "1000001001010011100000000000"

(0..str.size-3).each_with_object([]) do |i,a|
  next if str[i] == '0' || str[i+1] == '1'
  ndx = str[i+2..-1].index('1')
  a << [str[i+1, 1+ndx], i+1] if ndx
end
  #=> [["00000", 1], ["00", 7], ["0", 10], ["00", 12]]
```

Comment: You don't need to match zeros lazily, you can stay greedy, they're bounded by ones.

Comment: Thanks, @CasimiretHippolyte. Originally, I built a hash, rather than an array, with keys equal to the substrings. I wasn't getting all the matches and was puzzled. I was thinking of asking your help when it dawned on me that hashes don't have duplicate keys, that I needed an array, of course.

Comment: Instead of nesting the capture group in the lookahead, you could also use `/(?<=1)0+(?=1)/`. Nice side-effect: it returns a flat array when used within `scan`.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. Ever vigilant! I learned something from this. Originally, I was returning strings of zeroes bracketed with `1`'s, where I needed the lookbehind for the entire substring. When I decided to return only the zeroes I looked to see how I should modify my answer. I should have gone back to a blank sheet, in which case I probably would have seen what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get only the zeroes in between ones, you need to use regex lookbehind and lookahead:

```
(?:<=1)0+(?:=1)
```

After that you only need to get the max lenght element.